# Trouble installing Carbon Design System styles in Next.js 14 app

Tags: reactjs, next.js, carbon-design-system, carbon-components

I'm encountering issues while trying to install and apply the Carbon Design System styles to my Next.js 14 app. I've followed the [documentation](https://carbondesignsystem.com/developing/frameworks/react/) and attempted the following steps, but style seems not to be applied.

- `yarn add @carbon/react`
- import style in _app.tsx

```
import "@/styles/globals.css";

export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}
```

- @use in globals.css

```
/* globals.css */
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';

@use '@carbon/react';
```

- And then I import components in Home.tsx, but style seems not to be there.

```
import { Button, Form, TextInput } from "@carbon/react";

export default function Home() {
  return (
      <Form aria-label="Sign in">
        <div className="flex flex-col gap-1">
          <TextInput labelText="Username"/>
          <TextInput labelText="Password"/>
          <Button>Sign in</Button>
        </div>
      </Form>
  );
}
```

Despite these steps, style seems not to be applied.
See screenshot
[image]

Node.js version: v18.17.0 
npm. version: 9.6.7 
next.js version: 14.0.3 
Project structure: Pages Router

Question: 
Should I use instead `yarn add carbon-components`?

**UPDATE:** 
After converting `globals.css`. to `globals.scss` and replacing `@use 'carbon-components-react'`. to the top of the `globals.scss` `carbon components` started to highlight. Now the Problem is that by default it has no background and primary/blue background color is visible only on hover. 
See screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was fixed after adding this carbon import in `_app.tsx`.

```
import "@/styles/globals.scss";
import '@carbon/react/index.scss';
```